# php_fetch redirection failed?

Tags: php, forms

I'm very new to php. when I try to register a form through php. the data 
s are submitted to database but the redirection to a particular page is failed.

I have my login form named as index.php in root directory. and my registration form in second level directory. and my registration form control is in first level of directory. I used php_fetch for url sanitize. Here is my folder structure -

- root->inc(folder)
  ->index.php
- inc(folder)->pages(folder)
  ->registration.con.php
- pages(folder)->registrster.php

here is my form controls

```
<form class="js-validation-register form-horizontal push-50-t push-50" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="registration_form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-material form-material-success">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Please enter a username">
                                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-material form-material-success">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please provide your email">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-material form-material-success">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a strong password..">
                                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-material form-material-success">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="confirmpwd" name="confirmpwd" placeholder="..and confirm it">
                                        <label for="register-password2">Confirm Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label class="css-input switch switch-sm switch-success">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="register-terms" name="register-terms"><span></span> I agree with terms &amp; conditions
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
                                    <input class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="button" 
                                                                             value="Register" 
               onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                               this.form.username,
                               this.form.email,
                               this.form.password,
                               this.form.confirmpwd);" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

here is my php_fwtch function

```
function esc_url($url) {

if ('' == $url) {
    return $url;
}

$url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

$strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
$url = (string) $url;

$count = 1;
while ($count) {
    $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
}

$url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

$url = htmlentities($url);

$url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
$url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

if ($url[0] !== '/') {
    // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
    return '';
} else {
    return $url;
}
```

}

as you can see when i register a form on success it should redirect me to ../../index.php but insted it redirects me to ../index.php where registeration.con.php and functions exsits..!

this error is im getting on sucessful registration..

> Not Found

The requested URL /src3/inc/index.php was not found on this server.

i know it is redirecting to index page on inc folder.. but i have to redirect it to index page on the root directory..

please help me..

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.